# How to select number only regex

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am currently using the following code to select all the pages where my hotel ID is in the URL

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('pagePath'),array('visitors'),'-visitors','pagePath=~'.$hotelID,$startDate,$endDate,1,100);
```

The problem is if im looking for hotelID 10, it also selects pages where hotelID is 1002 for example

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this in the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) :

If the actually string is something like ?hotelID=10 then something like this should work. Place the following line as filters in the query explore.  Note: [^0-9] tells it that the next char cant be a number.  You will need to test that it still works if the next char doesn't exist, but I think it should work.

```
ga:pagePath=~hotelID=10[^0-9]
```

Your code should then look something like this I think:

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id,array('pagePath'),array('visitors'),'-visitors','pagePath=~hotelID='.$hotelID.'[^0-9]',$startDate,$endDate,1,100);
```